What does "Let's see how she "does" working as a chef" mean?

Its easy peasy to work in retail. Lets see how she DOES working as a chef.

What does "does" mean here?

No source...huh?

You didn't create that dialogue by yourself because you're asking about its meaning. So, where did you read it?

There are lots of definitions of "do" in most dictionaries. Do none of them fit?


It's easy peasy to work in retail. Let's see how she DOES working as a chef.

Please note your example missed out the two apostrophes.
Does can mean performs in a general sense.  However, as the two sentences contrast the work in retail (said to be ease peasy) and of a chef, other possible meanings of does are cope and manage, that is, words that give a sense of difficulty.
